# How to download .txt file from box.com on mac terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I do not have much experiance with the command line and I have done my research and still wasn't able to solve my problem.

I need to download a .txt file from a folder on box.com.

I attempted using:

```
 $ curl -o FILE URL
```

However, all I got was a empty text file that was named random numbers. I assumed the reason this happened is because the url of the file location does not end in .txt since it is in a file on box.com.

I also attempted:

```
 $ wget FILE URL
```

However, my mac terminal doesn't seem to find that command

Is there a different command that can download the file from box.com? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your curl is fine. It seems like that's what the server gave you. Verify the URL. Also, you can get wget with `brew install wget`.

Comment: I have confirmed the url, is it a problem with the url that is given by box.com? Also thank you I will go ahead and get wget and test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your URL in quotes to avoid shell trying to parse it:

```
curl -o myfile.txt "http://example.com/"
```

#### Update: If the URL requires authentication

Modern browsers allow you to export requests as `curl` commands.
For example, in Chrome, you can:

- open your file URL in a new tab
- open Developer tools (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools)
- switch to Network tab in the tools
- refresh the page, a request should appear in the "Network" tab
- Right-click the request, choose "Copy -> Copy as cURL"
- paste the command in the shell

Here's how it looks for this page for example:

[image: dev tools screenshot]

Comment: I attempted the command you provided. However, the file downloaded without the text that was in it.

Comment: when you open that URL in a browser what happens? do you need to be authenticated to open the URL?

Comment: Yes, you must sign into the account I believe since it is being hosted by Box.com.

Comment: if viewing the URL requires authentication, then you have to supply it to curl too. Is there a way to obtain a "sharing" link for that file that does not require authentication? You can test if a URL requires authentication by opening it in your browser in the "Incognito" mode. If it opens, it does not need auth.

Comment: Yes, the url requires authentication. I will do more research to find a way to "supply it to curl" Thank You.

Comment: added instructions on how to replay the request made through browser